# sailsjs & laterjs task scheduling, initialization.. poll every x or sleep for x?

Tags: node.js, sails.js, laterjs

I am building an open sourced nodejs powered sprinkler system which will run on the raspberry pi and work with the OpenSprinkler Pi.

**I am using:**

- sailsjs 0.9.3
- laterjs - for schedule interpretation and maths

  - i created an issue awhile back on bunkats repo asking for him to explain this to me.. https://github.com/bunkat/later/issues/19

The end result will be a REST api interface between rpi and whatever front-end you decide to develop for. web/mobile/cli .. etc.

The way the scheduling component will work is values will be posted to the url `/programs` with a zone id, name, intial status (false), and a plain text human readable schedule phrase such as: `every 12 hours starting on the 6th hour before 10 minutes` (06:00 & 18:00 for 10 mins).

This schedule will be parsed, and stringified and stored in db as such:

```
{\"schedules\":[{\"h\":[6,18],\"m_b\":[10]}],\"exceptions\":[],\"error\":-1}
```

The other values are cleaned and stored as they were entered.

### My question is:

how should I go about finding these schedules and determining their run time/date? I've got the scheduling part, and the run time down and working (run for 10 mins). I'm struggling with the theory behind efficiently retrieving the schedules though.

---

My initial thought was to have a interval every 1 mins poll the db...

```
setInterval(function(){
  //get programs from db
  //iterate through programs
  //enable programs which start now?
}, 60000);
```

But this seems kind of illogical. I suppose that when the schedule is created a `setInterval` or `setTimeout` is created with the appropriate scheduling info.. but what happens if the rpi loses power, or those could eat up a bit of memory having all of these intervals hanging out there..

- how will it handle existing schedules already in the db?

### open source repo

of what i have so far (not much other than the creation api/models/Programs.js) is here: 
https://github.com/RelativeMedia/nodesprinkler.git